# Meta value Array

Tags: custom-field, array

I am hoping someone can help me out.

I have created a custom meta box and trying to store an array, but when using `update_post_meta`, it doesn't seem to be storing it as an array.

I am getting the info via an api and it seems to be breaking down when going from the textarea to the `update_post_meta`.

I have tried `serialize`, `unserialize`, `maybe_serialize`, `maybe_unserialize` etc. Anyway here is my code.

```
$movieCast(array)

  array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'actor' => 'Anthony Hopkins',
    'actor_char' => 'Alfred Hitchcock',
    'actor_link' => 'anthony-hopkins',
    'img_path' => '/oDMLEhFmXLkTlUnErs0RxRua7kN.jpg',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'actor' => 'Helen Mirren',
    'actor_char' => 'Alma Reville',
    'actor_link' => 'helen-mirren',
    'img_path' => '/dRYchPNm8WCXxWHcGtUwq9VLra1.jpg',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'actor' => 'Scarlett Johansson',
    'actor_char' => 'Janet Leigh',
    'actor_link' => 'scarlett-johansson',
    'img_path' => '/dZ4uNJtLQkGlJ76eePrXYqUDWgn.jpg',
  ),...

echo "<textarea id='actors_array' name='actors_array' rows='5' cols='120'>" ?><?php var_export($movieCast); echo "</textarea>";
```

I have tested that the textarea is an array using `echo is_array($cast) ? 'Array' : 'not an Array';` and it's returning `Array`.

So I figure the problem is further down at save function

```
    $actors_array = $_POST['actors_array'];
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'actors_array', $actors_array );
```

Once stored and I use `$cast = get_post_meta` it seems it has not been stored correctly.

When testing `echo is_array($cast) ? 'Array' : 'not an Array';` it returns `not an array`.

```
echo"<pre>";print_r($cast);echo"</pre>";
```

returns

```
    array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'actor' => 'Anthony Hopkins',
    'actor_char' => 'Alfred Hitchcock',
    'actor_link' => 'anthony-hopkins',
    'img_path' => '/oDMLEhFmXLkTlUnErs0RxRua7kN.jpg',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'actor' => 'Helen Mirren',
    'actor_char' => 'Alma Reville',
    'actor_link' => 'helen-mirren',
    'img_path' => '/dRYchPNm8WCXxWHcGtUwq9VLra1.jpg',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'actor' => 'Scarlett Johansson',
    'actor_char' => 'Janet Leigh',
    'actor_link' => 'scarlett-johansson',
    'img_path' => '/dZ4uNJtLQkGlJ76eePrXYqUDWgn.jpg',
  ),...
```

So I am really hoping someone can help me out please.

Thanks :)

Comment: A single textarea cannot hold an array of values, when you collect that data from `$_POST` it's already a string value.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, I don't think this is a WordPress issue, just PHP.

When you `var_export` into the textarea, then submit that via `POST`, what you then have is not an array but a string. You can check `is_string` instead of `is_array` to confirm this.

If you want it to be an array again, you have to explicitly cast it as such:

```
$actors_array = $_POST['actors_array']; // $actors_array is a string
$actors_array = (array)$actors_array    // $actors_array is now an array
```

Comment: Turned it into an array but a var dump shows it as `array (size=1)
  0 => string 'array (
`

Comment: I assume because its nested arrays. The underlying issue is that you're going about this wrong, trying to create a data structure from a string from a textarea.

Comment: Yeah. I got it working though. Changed var_export to json_encode and then json_decode, works perfectly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ShannonHyland If that helped, please mark it as solution (the checkmark below the voting arrows on the upper left of this answer).